# How can i get tax codes from NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

Now i have 2 ways to get tax code from NetSuite and these are advantage/disadvantage of each

1/ The first way:

I get all tax code from saleTaxItem list and save in database, with this way, it's easy and fast.

But we must to check, employees/vendors has permission to use it. in result, SalesTaxItem object don't have any property refer to employees/vendors and Employee/Vendor object don't have refer key to SalesTaxItem too.

So, how can i know employee/vendor has permission to use taxcode with this way?

This is structure of SalesTaxItem Object:

```
                SalesTaxItem Object
                    (
                        [itemId] => Item Name
                        [displayName] => 
                        [description] => 
                        [rate] => 7.25%
                        [taxType] => 
                        [taxAgency] => RecordRef Object
                            (
                                [internalId] => -100
                                [externalId] => 
                                [type] => 
                                [name] => New Name
                            )

                        [purchaseAccount] => 
                        [saleAccount] => 
                        [isInactive] => 
                        [effectiveFrom] => 
                        [validUntil] => 
                        [eccode] => 
                        [reverseCharge] => 
                        [parent] => 
                        [exempt] => 
                        [isDefault] => 
                        [excludeFromTaxReports] => 
                        [available] => 
                        [export] => 
                        [taxAccount] => RecordRef Object
                            (
                                [internalId] => 37
                                [externalId] => 
                                [type] => 
                                [name] => New Name
                            )

                        [county] => Country Name
                        [city] => 
                        [state] => CA
                        [zip] => ,95646,96120
                        [nexusCountry] => 
                        [internalId] => -111
                        [externalId] => 
                        [nullFieldList] => 
                    )
```

2/ The second way:

I get employees list, vendors list. And foreach those lists to get taxcodes with function getSelectValueResult of NetsuiteService object.

With this way, with each employee/vendor we need call function getSelectValueResult to get taxcodes list of that employee/vendor. Althought we have 10 tax codes, but we need call function 1000 times (if we have 1000 employee/vendor).

Advantage of this way , we can save reference keys [taxcodes, employee], [taxcodes, vendor], it help check employee/vendor has permission to use tax code.

Disadvantage : slow and waste our time, and get duplicate tax code records.

This is structure of GetSelectValueResult Object when call function getSelectValueResult for each employee/vendor

```
            [getSelectValueResult] => GetSelectValueResult Object
                (
                    [status] => Status Object
                        (
                            [statusDetail] => 
                            [isSuccess] => 1
                        )

                    [totalRecords] => 2
                    [totalPages] => 1
                    [baseRefList] => BaseRefList Object
                        (
                            [baseRef] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => RecordRef Object
                                        (
                                            [internalId] => 25821
                                            [externalId] => 
                                            [type] => platformCore:RecordRef
                                            [name] => My tax code name 1
                                        )

                                    [1] => RecordRef Object
                                        (
                                            [internalId] => 27812
                                            [externalId] => 
                                            [type] => platformCore:RecordRef
                                            [name] => My tax code name 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )
```

Which one i should to use ?

I think first way is good, but how can i check permission of employee/vendor when use taxcode?

Thank you very much.

Comment: With second way, i can send employees list / vendors list to get , it's faster get by each employee. But even if has one employee don't have permission , INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION return . I think set ignoreReadOnlyFields to true will ignore errors. How i can set ignoreReadOnlyFields in NetSuite PHP Toolkit 2013 ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Individual Tax codes does not have permission, you can get the roles of the employees separately and store it in a separate table. So you can join the roles whenever you need.

Comment: Do you say about roles as Administrator, CEO ? How can we know employee has permission to use tax Code with Roles ?

Comment: I see Employee class has 'rolesList' property, don't have property refer to tax Codes

Comment: In the UI, I could see the role Under Role -> Permissions tab -> Lists -> Tax Items. You should be able to get this information from suitescript or webservices.